# /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver: /usr/pgsql-12/lib/libpq.so.5: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver)

Tags: r, rstudio-server

i'm using CENTOS.7, while trying to run the rstudio-server start command to start Rstudio on my machine it brings me back this error

```
-bash-4.2$ rstudio-server start
/usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver: /usr/pgsql-12/lib/libpq.so.5: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/rstudio-server/bin/rserver)
Unable to open config file: /etc/rstudio/rserver.conf
2021-11-04T10:17:50.482013Z [rserver] ERROR system error 2 (No such file or directory) [path: /etc/rstudio/rserver.conf, description: Unable to open config file: /etc/rstudio/rserver.conf]; OCCURRED AT rstudio::core::Error rstudio::core::FilePath::openForRead(std::shared_ptr<std::basic_istream<char> >&) const src/cpp/shared_core/FilePath.cpp:1453; LOGGED FROM: bool rstudio::core::program_options::parseConfigFile(rstudio_boost::program_options::variables_map&, const string&, const rstudio::core::program_options::OptionsDescription&, bool) src/cpp/core/ProgramOptions.cpp:136
```

Has anyone had the same problem? Thank you in advance for your feedback.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Try using the SUDO command prior to the command, to run it as an administrator.

See this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3063/how-do-i-run-a-command-as-the-system-administrator-root).

You also need, of course, to have admin rights to the OS.